# Small fonts on Bootstrap DateTime picker

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I´m using the Bootstrap 3 DateTime picker from [www.github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://www.github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Everything is working fine, except that I need to use small fonts and less spacing between the calendar grid lines.

Does anyone has an idea on how to do it. This is the original code:

```
<div class="small">
    <div id="myPlaceholder"></div>
</div>
```

And on Javascript:

```
 $('#myPlaceholder').datetimepicker({
                language : 'en'
            });
```

It works well, but does not show small fonts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to add your own CSS to style the date picker.

This will make the columns narrower:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget td.day {
    width: 200px;
}
```

This will make the rows shorter:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget td.day {
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

This makes the font smaller for the day numbers:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget td.day {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

And combining them all:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget td.day {
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

And as a bonus, this will make the font size of the day of week smaller:

```
th.dow {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Working. What about table cell padding and the month selector text. I would like to reduce that too.

Comment: All I did was inspect the HTML to figure out the elements, give it a try.

Comment: @VenkataTata Er, OK, and what do you expect me (or anyone) to do about that?